# How would I connect to a remote MySQL database using Swift 3?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, swift, cocoa, fmdb

What I want to do is ask the server if the user is in the "accounts" table, and if so, then what is the password. The problem is, I can't connect to the server at all. A search on the internet and i'm left with nothing. I have imported FMDB into my project and have a username and password field as well as a login button. When the button is clicked, I want the application to connect to the server and execute the above sql. I need some direction, I have tried doing `let db = FMDatabase(path: "http://example.com?username=foo&password=bar")`

```
let db = FMDatabase(path: "foo@example.com")
```

etc.

I have allowed my ip in the sql settings, and have an account setup to manage the database. I need to know the server address, and the data that needs to be sent to allow me access through the application to the database.

Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do here

Thanks

Comment: FMDB won't help you.

Comment: Is this on iOS or macOS?

Comment: @ryantxr MacOS, Cocoa

Comment: @El Tomato I just figured it would be a little bit easier for me, I've never used remote SQL especially with Swift before.